# Is it safer to have checks sent directly from the bank?

Tags: check, payment, checking-account

Is it safer to have checks sent directly from the bank using online 'bill payer'?Is your personal account number and routing number on those checks?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Safer that what?  Do you think it's unsafe to send a personal check just because is has routing info on it?

Answer (score 3):

When I used Bill Pay heavily (on a now-closed account), they were processed as regular checks.  The money did *not* come out of the account immediately and my bank account number was on the check.  Some payments were made electronically rather than by physical check.  I did not have to pay a fee per check, but if I didn't meet certain requirements (balance minimum or a direct deposit paycheck), they would charge a monthly fee.  Obviously I can't say that other systems worked the same way.

The electronic payments may have been safer than making a regular payment.

The routing number identifies your bank, not you.  Even if they use a different one for the Bill Pay payments, it will still identify the correct bank.  And even if they use the same one, it won't identify you, just your bank.

Comment: Here's your upvote. Good job on earning 5k rep!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it probably is safer to use a bill pay check. It is also less convenient because the money taken from your account immediately, and you usually have to pay a fee for expedited handling.

Based on the terms you are using here, I am going to assume you are in the US. The answer to this question may vary from one bank to another, but I have seen a pattern with many banks. Whether your bank does this cannot be answered without knowing who you bank with, and frankly, without receiving a check from your bank, I still probably wouldn't be able to find an answer online if yours isn't one of the big banks.

Many banks will issue a check from an account that the bank uses specifically for the purposes of "Bill Pay" checks. That check may or may not have the same routing number as you own checks, but not the same account number. The check will also have an expiration date 90-180 days from the issue date.